# Mute htlm5 video player with jQuery after seconds

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have html5 video player:

```
    <video width="185" height="104" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
    <source src="comm.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
```

It is a 5 seconds video. I want loop, but I want to mute this video once it has played for the first time.

jQuery masters... I'm looking for your help.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){$("video").prop('muted', true);},5000);

Comment: I need muted loop.  Video should have voice only for one time. Then muted..

Comment: ^ That's why I wrapped 'the mute' in a method which will execute the mute after 5 seconds (the timeout - it's a delay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comment - one way would be setting the video to mute via a timeout after n seconds. I would prefer something like this:

```
// use all videos with a loop attribute
// remove the attribute and replay on end event
$('video[loop]').bind('ended', function(){
  // prop or attr depends on your jquery version
  $(this).attr('muted', true);
  this.play();
}).removeAttr('loop');
```